# scrollable div, jumping content on appearing scrollbar (!not! html or body) (and only with css)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a problem on jumping content in a scrollable div (overflow-y: auto).
the question is NOT how to solve it for the page html or body elements, which all "solutions" are pointing to. I need one for a scrollable div with dynamic content. the scrollbar should not be always visible, too (so overflow-y: scroll is not acceptable). and also this must be a fix with css only.
I have a fiddle for this:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/4n1au2Ly/][1]
```

there you can vertically shrink the output panel to see the appearing scrollbar and the moving content. so, how to fix that? thank you very much :)

Comment: sorry for the broken link appearance. I cannot find the edit button. so here again, the link: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/4n1au2Ly/](http://jsfiddle.net/4n1au2Ly/)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS only solution this problem simply doesn't exist. You have to rely on JavaScript to achieve this. To do this with JavaScript:

1. Listen for page load (`DOMContentLoaded`) and `resize` event.
2. Set the width for your `div` in absolute pixels.
3. Whenever above events are fired, recalculate the width of `div` and set it to parent width and also subtracting reasonable default for scrollbar say 20px.

Answer (score -1):

I am not understand question at all, but can `overflow-y: auto;` fix your problem?

Comment: no, **I am** using `overflow-y: auto;`. **this** is the problem, because this is leading to the problem described above ;)

Comment: Sory, I don't see it in container class, I have pointed it to alphabet class

Comment: but it IS the container class ;) : 
`.container{
    overflow-y:auto; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    height:100vh;
    width:500px;
}`